# Networking, switchers, repeaters

Tags: networking

Determine on which devices will signal appear
If computer-A sends a message(notification) to computer-B (`Sw - switcher`, `R - repeater`).

Here is image:
[image]

Comment: I don't know, so I thought here I can find the solution cause I need it too much@HAL

Comment: If you read a little about switches and repeaters, you'll be able to answer yourself. Please try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R4 and Sw: because package's trip is A->R4-Sw (route package to B)->R4->B

Comment: It can be. Are you sure in your answer?

Comment: `Could it be R4 and Sw?` does not sound like an answer to me.

Comment: That depends of What do you mean by repeaters. If for you, repeaters can route packages then signal/package/message has no need to pass through switcher but if repeaters can´t route then packages has to pass through switcher who is capable for routing.

Comment: I have this task from university and have no idea what does it mean. The problem is that I need to have solution in an hour with explanation of it so I have no time to read about this stuff. So if you or someone can do this, please help!

Comment: Well, you could use my answer if it helps you, but you really need to read about repeaters and switchers (their basic functions or capabilities) to be sure about my answer. At least read about if repeaters can or not route packages. That means if has the intelligence to know source and destination. This usually is related to a hardware implementation, so read about it and use my answer y you want. Good Luck!

Comment: You're welcome! I don't understand why my first answer has negatives, what I do wrong?